# GWT does not work with Spring REST service

Tags: spring, rest, gwt, data-conversion

I wrote a Spring REST application. I tested it with curl command and it worked truly.

In another GWT Ajax application I have an RequestBuilder object that it does not work with my Spring Rest: after calling sendRequest method, the event `onResponseReceived` is fired but the `getText` method returns an empty string.

this is a part of my spring servlet.xml configuration file

```
<bean id="jsonmembertemplate" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" >
    <property name="contentType" value="text/javascript;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <property name="disableCaching" value="false"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
```

and a part of my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/member/get/{memberid}")
public String getMember(Model model, @PathVariable("memberid") int id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    model.addAttribute("member", memberDao.get(id));
    return "jsonmembertemplate";
}
```

and gwt code

```
private RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "http://localhost:8080/depna-nat-server/member/get/1?");



try {
                rb.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript;charset=UTF-8");
                rb.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                        Window.alert(Integer.toString(response.getStatusCode()));
                        Window.alert(response.getStatusText());
                        Window.alert(Integer.toString(response.getText().length()));
                        area.setText(response.getText());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                        Window.alert("fail");
                    }
                });
            } catch (RequestException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: What about `getStatusCode()`? And what's the browser saying in its developer tools (hint: hit the F12 key)

Comment: Google chrome message in console tab :
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/depna-nat-server/member/get/1. Origin http://127.0.0.1:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy and https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT's

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of gwt applications working with json and xml rest services offered by spring, we use spring instead of gwt (rpc or rf) because these services are offered to 3party apps as well.

I started my first project with RequestBuilder and we dind't have any problem, so maybe you have some issue in your code, could you inspect the traffic and post the errors you have?

If you are running a cross-domain issue (statusCode=0 normally means it) , add a filter to your servlet container, take a look to [this document](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#CORS_%28Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing%29).

I finally opted to use [gwtquery-ajax](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax) and [gquery-data-binding](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBinding) because it made really easy to consume these services and to map them to java objects.

Comment: you are right!, I had the same problem with status code = 0, and now I see the error in the FF console, thanks